# The useage of circles.js in the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm now make a some circle in the html. however I can't handle circles.js library.

Library URL : https://github.com/lugolabs/circles

My source code is below.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="circles.js"></script>
<script>
  Circles.create({
    id:         'circles-1',
    percentage: 43,
    radius:     60,
    width:      10,
    number:     7.13,
    text:       '%',
    colors:     ['#D3B6C6', '#4B253A'],
    duration:   400
  })
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="canvas">
<div class="circle" id="circles-1"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Actually, I didn't learn how to use the javascript in the html. So I was in a trouble by using javascript. how know solve that? or give advices to study the javascript?

Comment: see here : https://github.com/lugolabs/circles/blob/master/spec/index.html

Comment: @ihemant360 Thanks you so much! that's is simple example!

Comment: is it your answer you are looking for !! can i post it in answer section. or if you need any extra advice  .. ask